# Corona Sdk: storyboard API and object alpha (opacity)

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i am having troubles changing an object alpha in a storyboard corona application.

When the page is loaded, the object has a default alpha of 0 (it is invisible).
Then, by clicking on a button, his alpha is set to 1 (it becomes visible).

If i leave the page, move to another storyboard page, and then get back, the object is still visible, even though i set his alpha back to 0 again with this code both in the function that gets me back to other pages:

```
local function gotoHomefun()
if objectname then
objectname.alpha = 0
end
storyboard.gotoScene( "home", "crossFade", 400 )
return true
end
```

and in the destroyScene event:

```
function scene:destroyScene( event )
local group = self.view
if objectname then
objectname.alpha = 0
objectname :removeSelf()    
objectname = nil
end
display.remove( group )
group = nil     
end
```

I really don't know if im doing something wrong, or i found a bug.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you call the `removeScene` or `purgeScene` from other scene??

if not then your scene won't be removed unless it is a low memory situation. Try setting executing the current code in the `exitScene` event which gets called whenever the view is changed to new scene.

Refer to this doc for the event specific detail - 
[Storyboard Lifecycle Events](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/11/14/introducing-the-storyboard-api/)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Purge scene was the key.

I'd upvote this if i had 15 reputation, eheh. 

Thanks again!